# TypeError when trying to execute the aggregate function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I was trying out the aggregate function which was being taught in the lecture video. I have been facing an error while executig it.

```
sumCount = flightsParsed.map(lambda x:x.DEP_DELAY).aggregate((0,0),(lambda acc,value:(acc[0]+value,acc[1]+1)),(lambda acc1,acc2:(acc1[0]+acc2[0],acc1[1]+acc2[1])))
```

The error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

PS: I have been trying the exercies on Databricks, by loading the CSV as a DF with inferschema set to `True' , and then converted it to an RDD for further processing.

From what I infer from the error statement is there is a none value being passed to the lambda. Is there any way i could see the output of the lambda functions alone to debug where the exact problem is occuring?

Comment: you could always rewrite the lambda as an actual function and print the values

Comment: One of `acc[0]`, `value`, `acc[1]`, `acc1[0]`, `acc2[0]`,  `acc1[0]`, `acc2[0]` is `None`. You can break it down as suggest in the other comment and have a closer look.